# Why is my laptop (Debian 10) only connecting with 100Mbit/s instead of Gigabit?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

My laptop *(Thinkpad T450s)* with Debian 10 only connects with 100Mbit/s instead of Gigabit through ethernet, although the network card should be capable of Gigabit LAN *(see #2 below)*. I tried a machine running Ubuntu 18.04 on the same cable *(see #5 below)* and it got Gigabit.

If I manually set link speed to 1000Mbit/s, nothing changes. If I enable *auto-negotiation*, it won't even connect and after disabling *auto-negotiation* again it can't connect anymore. I then have to delete the ethernet-connection in the network manager GUI and create a new one with *auto-negotiation* disabled.

- According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation#Standardization_and_interoperability), *auto-negotiation* is required for Gigabit LAN, so I suspect *auto-negotiation* somehow failing might be the root of the problem.
  Then again, *auto-negotiation* seems to have worked from a live Ubuntu 18.04 on the same machine, in the sense that I had internet, but with a link speed of 100 Mbit/s, so I'm unsure at this point.

How do I configure my network settings correctly in order to use Gigabit LAN?

---

EDIT: In the end I just bought a Gigabit Ethernet USB 3 adapter for 20€ as this seemed like the most pragmatic solution.

---

These are the diagnostic steps I've run so far:

1. `sudo ethtool enp0s25`:

   ```
   Settings for enp0s25:
     Supported ports:              [ TP ]
     Supported link modes:         10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                   100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                   1000baseT/Full
     Supported pause frame use:    No
     Supports auto-negotiation:    Yes
     Supported FEC modes:          Not reported
     Advertised link modes:        Not reported
     Advertised pause frame use:   No
     Advertised auto-negotiation:  No
     Advertised FEC modes:         Not reported

     Speed:                  100Mb/s
     Duplex:                 Full
     Port:                   Twisted Pair
     PHYAD:                  1
     Transceiver:            internal
     Auto-negotiation:       off
     MDI-X:                  on (auto)
     Supports Wake-on:       pumbg
     Wake-on:                g
     Current message level:  0x00000007 (7)
                             drv probe link
     Link detected:          yes
   ```
2. `lscpi`:

   ```
   00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM (rev 03)
   ```

According to Intel, the card supports Gigabit LAN *(see [here](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/71307/intel-ethernet-connection-i218-lm.html))* and there seems to be no firmware missing. I checked with `dmesg | grep -i firm` and it says (Bluetooth edited out):
`[254037.281327]  (NULL device *):  firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq [254037.281525]  (NULL device *):  firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode [255529.699990]  (NULL device *):  firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode [259054.226196]  (NULL device *):  firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq [259054.229879]  (NULL device *):  firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode [269591.798078]  (NULL device *):  firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode`
3. `sudo lspci -k -nn -s 00:19.0`:
`00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM [8086:15a2] (rev 03) Subsystem:              Lenovo Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM [17aa:2226] Kernel driver in use:   e1000e Kernel modules:         e1000e`
`sudo modinfo e1000e | grep -e ^filename -e ^vermagic -e ^parm`:
```
filename:   /lib/modules/4.19.0-8-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
vermagic:   4.19.0-8-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions

````
parm:   debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)
parm:   copybreak:Maximum size of packet that is copied to a new buffer on receive (uint)
parm:   TxIntDelay:Transmit Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:   TxAbsIntDelay:Transmit Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:   RxIntDelay:Receive Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:   RxAbsIntDelay:Receive Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:   InterruptThrottleRate:Interrupt Throttling Rate (array of int)
parm:   IntMode:Interrupt Mode (array of int)
parm:   SmartPowerDownEnable:Enable PHY smart power down (array of int)
parm:   KumeranLockLoss:Enable Kumeran lock loss workaround (array of int)
parm:   WriteProtectNVM:Write-protect NVM [WARNING: disabling this can lead to corrupted NVM] (array of int)
parm:   CrcStripping:Enable CRC Stripping, disable if your BMC needs the CRC (array of int)
```
````

4. I booted Ubuntu 18.04 from a LiveUSB and ran the same speed test, receiving 90/40mbps down/up. `ethtool` reported link speed 100Mbit/s with *auto-negotiation* enabled *(by default, not manually set by me)*, and `sudo ethtool -s enp0s25 speed 1000` reported `cannot advertise link speed 1000`
5. I *used the same cable (15m CAT6)* on another machine, running Ubuntu 18.04 with *auto-negotiation* enabled, and Gigabit worked *(confirmed it with a [speed test](https://www.speedtest.net/))*. LED on the access point was flashing green, instead of yellow, as is the case with my machine.  The report of the speed test was 250/84Mbps down/up on the Ubuntu machine vs 90/40Mbps down/up on the Debian one. 
     `ethtool`: *(Ubuntu machine)*

   ```
   Settings for enx00e04c6845e0:
     Supported ports:              [ TP MII ]
     Supported link modes:         10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                   100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                   1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
     Supported pause frame use:    No
     Supports auto-negotiation:    Yes
     Supported FEC modes:          Not reported
     Advertised link modes:        10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                   100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                   1000baseT/Full
     Advertised pause frame use:   Symmetric Receive-only
     Advertised auto-negotiation:  Yes
     Advertised FEC modes:         Not reported

     Link partner advertised link modes:         10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                                 100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                                 1000baseT/Full
     Link partner advertised pause frame use:    Symmetric
     Link partner advertised auto-negotiation:   Yes
     Link partner advertised FEC modes:          Not reported

     Speed:                  1000Mb/s
     Duplex:                 Full
     Port:                   MII
     PHYAD:                  32
     Transceiver:            internal
     Auto-negotiation:       on
     Supports Wake-on:       pumbg
     Wake-on:                d
     Current message level:  0x00007fff (32767)
                             drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err tx_queued intr tx_done rx_status pktdata hw wol
     Link detected:          yes
   ```

   - **Note:** the whole set of options starting with `Link partner advertised`  is missing from my output; Is it possible my machine doesn't understand the advertisement of *auto-negotiation* from the AP?
6. Someone pointed out that *Green Ethernet* or *Energy Efficient Ethernet* (eee) might be the problem, so I tried disabling it with
   `ethtool --set-eee eth0 eee off`, as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255810/turn-down-the-energy-efficient-ethernet-eee-aka-green-ethernet), but nothing changed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106786/discussion-on-question-by-c4x-why-is-my-laptop-debian-10-only-connecting-with).

Comment: Maybe you should try what's suggested here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/download-install-ethtool-under-debian-ubuntu-linux/ EDIT: and also here (https://forum.manjaro.org/t/ethernet-consistently-at-100mbps-half-duplex/73178/7), there's a permanent solution proposed by "tbd", about mid-page. Doesn't matter if the distro and the commands are different, it's transposable to your distro since the package is widely available.

Comment: @Didier: Thank you for looking that up for me. The first link is just an ethtool-cheat-sheat basically? About the solution in the second link: I tried it, but it didn't change anything, neither in the output of `ethtool` nor in the measured download speed.

Comment: There are a few tests you can run, and some finetuning to be done, based on what it says here (https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/performance-tuning/ethernet.html) and here (https://datatag.web.cern.ch/howto/tcp.html). There are no guarantees, of course, but it's worth a try. Now, if you can achieve true Gigabit speeds with Ubuntu and not with Debian, then it's most probably a software issue.

Comment: @Didier: These links are very interesting, but it seems they are more meant for people with a gigabit connection that is slower than possible, whereas I don't even have a gigabit connection at all.
Please note that I achieved Gigabit with Ubuntu on another machine, Ubuntu on a live stick on my machine had 100Mb/s, although *auto-negotiation* seems to have worked.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part about it being on another machine, sorry. Maybe the NIC on this one simply can't accomodate true Gigabit speed on full duplex. It might peak over the 100Mbps limit for a few moments until buffer is full, and will return to "normal" afterwards.

Comment: EDIT: you don't happen to have "Green Ethernet" activated on this machine, by chance? Can't remember if this bit (no pun intended) of info came up in this already long thread. EDIT: does this look like your PC datasheet? http://www.lenovoarvutid.ee/files/datasheet-lenovo-thinkpad-t450.pdf

Comment: @Didier: I'm not sure whether I have *Green Ethernet* activated. Is it the same as *Energy Efficient Ethernet*? If so, I'm also not sure if it is activated, but I tried disabling it with ´ethtool --set-eee eth0 eee off´ as described in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255810/turn-down-the-energy-efficient-ethernet-eee-aka-green-ethernet) post - no result
The datasheet looks similar yes. I have the T450s instead of the T450 but I think the differences are small.

Comment: Since you're getting the same issue while booted to different OSes on the same machine, it's likely the ethernet port itself.  Auto-negotiation _must_ be used, else you'll need to manually re-wire your ethernet cable to be a crossover cable.

Comment: @JW0914: Sounds interesting!
Are you saying that my NIC is alright but the RJ45-port or the connector on my motherboard might be damaged? Could you think of any way for me  to corroborate that theory?
Note that the issue is not completely the same with different OSes on the same machine though: With Debian, if I enable *auto-negotiation* I lose connectivity instantly. On Ubuntu I can enable it but it will still only result in a 100Mbit/s connection.

Comment: @C4X You should be able to find how to test whether an ethernet port is bad via google. As to the experience on Debian vs Ubuntu, you'd have to do more research, but my guess is Ubuntu used the auto-negotiated Tx & Rx assignments even after disabling auto-negotiation, whereas Debian cleared those assignments, resulting in no communication; but again, this is only a guess & needs to be verified _(simplification: w/o CAT6 auto-negotiation, the Tx & Rx lines of a regular ethernet cable on one machine is connected to the same on the other - `Tx <-> Tx`/`Rx <-> Rx`  versus `Tx <-> Rx`/`Rx <-> Tx`)_